# How to extract coefs and powers of polynomial from a string in C?

Tags: c, string, parsing, split

The exact question in the header.

e.g. `1*x^5-10*x^3+3*x^2+5`

I'm trying to use `strtok`:

```c
char str[] = "1*x^5-10*x^3+3*x^2+5";
char *token = strtok(str, "*x^+-");

while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "*x^+-");
}
```

But in this case I lose negative values.

How can I fix that? I can only use `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, `string.h`.

e.g.

Input: `1*x^5-10*x^3+3*x^2+5`

Output: 1 5 -10 3 3 2 5

Comment: Please make a [mre] to demonstrate. Use multiple examples, with good cases and fail cases.

Comment: You can't use `strtok` as it makes you loose the separator character (like `-`). You need to do "manual" tokenization on the `+` or `-` to separate the terms, *keeping* the sign. Then extract the coefficients while also keeping track of the sign.

Comment: This approach will also fail on "7*x^3-x" because you don't know what each number is. Roll your own parser.

Comment: If they are integer coefficients and powers you can use `strtol` which will tell you where the next character is.

Comment: How do you know that the `-` is not operator but negative sign. Having two numbers `5 -10` side by side without operator doesn't make sense